# Proof verification of finding the maximum order of a group generated by two elements satisfying some relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is the group generated by $a,b$ satisfying the relations $a^8=b^2a^4=ab^{-1}ab=e$. I wish to show that $G$ has order at most 16.
There is already a solution to this problem here [order of group generated by two element with some relation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070901/order-of-group-generated-by-two-element-with-some-relation) but I did not find it natural to follow, for example since that was rather wordy with unnatural objects, so I am writing my own solution which is very brief and natural:

$ab=ba^{-1}=ba^7$ so $ba=aba^{-6}=a^2ba^{-5}=...=a^7b$ so that every element of $G$ is of the form $a^ib^j$. In addition, $b^2=a^4$ so that in the representation $a^ib^j$, $j=0,1$. Also, of course $i=0,1,...,7$. So the maximum order is $2*8=16$.

Is my solution right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof looks correct to me (and I agree that yours is a bit more intuitive than the link you provided, though you pursue essentially the same strategy).